# Strategy Pattern : Same group of function but takes different numbers of parameter

Tags: c#, design-patterns

My post's title may not be the appropriate one anyway, I came across a design problem recently and though I think it's a very common but yet I'm not very sure how to solve it.

I have tow type of command sets.

Example for first type:

> create_room 4

In the above command `create_room` is the command and `4` is the data on which the operation will be performed.

Example for second type:

> exit

Which does not take any data to operate on.

My strategy is:

```
public interface ICommandExecutor
{
    stirng Execute (string command);
}
public class CreateRoom : ICommandExecutor
{
    public string Execute (string command)
    {
        //do the job
    }
}
public class Exit : ICommandExecutor
{
    public string Execute (string command)
    {
        //do the job
    }
}
```

Before that I have a factory to decide which version of implementation to be called based on command input.

```
ICommandExecutor executor = null;
if (command.Contains("exit"))
{
    executor = new Exit();
}
else if (command.Contains("create_room"))
{
    executor = new CreateRoom();
}
```

Now my problem here is with the implementation of the class `Exit`.
The method `public string Execute (string command)` takes a parameter. Which is the command itself; in case if we have any data to operate on (like `create_room 4`). Command `exit` takes no data to operate on, so it is totally not necessary to pass the parameter. But my design forces me to pass it. What would be a better way to solve this problem.

Comment: Arguments to `Command` objects should be properties on the command, and the `Execute` method shouldn't take anything.

Comment: @Amy Thanks for support, I though of the way but never been so clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Command pattern is supposed to encapsulate the entire command, including its parameters.  You should be able to serialize a command, store it somewhere, restore it, deserialize it, and *still execute it*.

So, to properly use the `Command` pattern, make the parameters properties of the command, not as arguments to `Execute()`:

```
public interface ICommandExecutor
{
    string Execute ();
}
public class CreateRoom : ICommandExecutor
{
    public string RoomName { get; set; }

    public string Execute ()
    {
        //do the job
    }
}
public class Exit : ICommandExecutor
{
    public string Execute ()
    {
        //do the job
    }
}
```

Then its usage:

```
ICommandExecutor executor = null;
if (command.Contains("exit"))
{
    executor = new Exit();
}
else if (command.Contains("create_room"))
{
    executor = new CreateRoom()
    {
        RoomName = // get room name from command, perhaps using a regex?
    };
}

if (executor != null)
{
    executor.Execute();
}
```